# How to send multiple keywords in a loop to search using selenium and python?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm currently passing a single keyword into a search box and clicking the search button using selenium. I get the proper page by doing so. Below is my working code for a single keyword.

```
page = driver.get('my_url')
searchbox = driver.find_elements_by_name('searchterm')[1]

#pass search keywords here
searchbox.send_keys('key1') # single keyword passed
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'submit-btn')]")
button.click()

"""
Extract data from links
"""
div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-result')
links_list = []
for tags in div:
    links = (tags.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'))
    for elem in links:
        links_list.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
```

However, I want to pass in a list of keywords so the code iterates for each item in the list. For example, if I have a list

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...]
for key in keys:
    page = driver.get('my_url')
    searchbox = driver.find_elements_by_name('searchterm')[1]

    #pass search keywords here
    searchbox.send_keys(key) # single keyword passed
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'submit-btn')]")
    button.click()

    """
    Extract data from links
    """
    div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-result')
    links_list = []
    for tags in div:
        links = (tags.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'))
        for elem in links:
            links_list.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
```

How will I pass in the next keyword in the list as a search term and perform the same operations? Obviously I have tried using a for loop to iterate through a list of keywords, but this is not working as the results are only giving me the search results of the first keyword in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would work?

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
links_list = []

# loop through all keys and search for them
for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_elements_by_name('searchterm')[1]
    searchbox.send_keys(key)
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'submit-btn')]")
    button.click()

    # go through all the search results per key and add them to the links_list
    div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-result')
    for tags in div:
        links = (tags.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'))
        for elem in links:
            links_list.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately not so simple. I tried implementing this before writing this question but I got an error: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException often occur when you have a WebElement variable and then the page changes. This makes the reference to the element on the page invalid. Hence why I looked up the WebElement variable again within each iteration in the loop. If you initialize the the `searchbox` element outside of the first loop, I would expect these errors, as the page changes or refreshes after searching.
Did you copy paste my code to see if it actually works?

Comment: So I copied your code, and now it works. Seems that aside from the fix you mentioned for the error, the other problem was that I was initializing the empty links_list inside the loop. Calling it outside the loop was the fix. Appreciate the civil help, just one of those brain fart moments. :)

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for statement and iterate over your list

```
for key in keys:       
    searchbox.send_keys(key) # single keyword passed
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'submit-btn')]")
    button.click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not so simple. The code still only reads the first keyword and gets relevant search results.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question *currently you are passing a single keyword into a search box and clicking the search button you get the proper page by doing so*. Now if you want to pass in a list of keywords so the code iterates for each item in the list you can declare the *List* e.g. and pass the *List* items one by one in a loop as follows :

```
keys = ['Selenium', 'WebDriver', 'guru']
# other lines of code
initial_url = driver.current_url
for key in keys:
    searchbox = driver.find_elements_by_name('searchterm')[1]

    #pass search keywords here
    searchbox.send_keys('key') # single keyword passed
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'submit-btn')]")
    button.click()

    """
    Extract data from links
    """
    div = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-result')
    links_list = []
    for tags in div:
        links = (tags.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'))
        for elem in links:
        links_list.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
    driver.get(initial_url)
```

Comment: I know that the code requires a for loop where a list is iterated. That is not the issue. I had been trying to implement a for loop iterating through a list of keywords, but each time I get the error message: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document